# D3 Bar Chart drawing a horizontal line using Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a Bar Chart that takes an array of objects and spits out a bar chart with a horizontal line using the path method provided by the d3. The problem is the horizontal line does not extend to the entire graph when the data pool is small. I'm unsure on how to resolve this issue. I have working code https://codesandbox.io/s/88onwvrm80.

My data looks like this:

```
const data = [
  { activity: "Main Idea and Detail", value: 90, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Character and Plot", value: 80, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Elements of Poetry", value: 70, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Standard 8.10", value: 60, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "8.1.3", value: 50, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 6", value: 40, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 7", value: 30, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 8", value: 21, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 9", value: 10, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 10", value: 5, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "8.1.34", value: 50, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 60", value: 40, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 70", value: 30, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 80", value: 21, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 90", value: 10, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 100", value: 5, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 900", value: 100, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 1000", value: 50, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill -1", value: 5, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "8.1.35", value: 50, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 160", value: 40, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 10", value: 30, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 20", value: 21, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 80", value: 10, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 650", value: 5, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 300", value: 100, color: "#2A78E4" },
  { activity: "Skill 3000", value: 50, color: "#2A78E4" }
];
```

If I delete several objects from the array, the line no longer extends to the entire graph.

My path looks like this:

```
if (data) {
      path = d3
        .line()
        .x((info, index) => {
          return xScales(info.activity) * index;
        })
        .y(() => {
          return yScales(baseLine - 1.2);
        });
    }
```

And the actual chart

```
 <svg width={1500} height={height} className={styles.svg} ref="svg">
            >
            {data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <rect
                  key={index}
                  width={xScales.bandwidth()}
                  x={xScales(data.activity)}
                  y={yScales(data.value)}
                  fill={data.color}
                  height={height - margin.bottom - yScales(data.value)}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.props.updateSelectedBarColor(index);
                    this.props.onBarClick();
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
            <g
              ref="xAxis"
              transform={`translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`}
              className={styles.axisBottom}
            />
            <g ref="yAxis" transform={`translate(${margin.left} ,5)`} />
            <path
              d={path(data)}
              className={styles.baseLine}
              style={{
                strokeWidth: 2,
                stroke: `${baseLineColor}`
              }}
              id="myPath"
            />
```

Comment: why do you draw the horizontal line in M segments, just draw it from the left to the right in one step/segment.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: feed the `d3.line` a data set with just 2 points, both ends of the chart x-axis, you know the x-values so easy to construct the array with 2 points